# Change button width and height through code

Tags: android, button, layout, size

I am trying to change the `width` and `height` of `Buttons` I dynamically create but my code below is not working. The `Buttons` stays the same default size. Anyone know why this is not working?

I believe it might have to do with this line:

```
 myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The problem may be that I am not supposed to create new `LinearLayout` params each time but rather add it to an existing `LayoutParam`?

What do you guys think?

```
public void onClick(View view)
    {

        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());

        linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      

        int size = enter_txt.getText().toString().length();

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            Button myButton = new Button(view.getContext());
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            myButton.setWidth(100);
            myButton.setHeight(100);
            myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
            linearLayout2.addView(myButton, rlp);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code :

```
myButton.setWidth(100);
myButton.setHeight(100);
```

To this :

```
myButton.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
myButton.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

And yes, in your case you can replace :

```
myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

To :

```
myButton.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

Comment: thanks this is it! myButton.setLayoutParams(rlp) fixed it. I wasn't sure if I could use rlp for the LayoutParams since I already use rlp to add the views to the linear layout: linearLayout2.addView(myButton, rlp);

Comment: @user2456977 You welcome :) Just try it! Using rlp should be  okay because its also a LinearLayout with WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

You can use other constructor of the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, which receiving width and height:

```
myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
```